# Display Category Name and Date Posted on Blog Post

Tags: categories, date

I am using Astra Theme wordpress >5.0 version
I want To Display Category name at top left corner of my Blog post Like Category:Technology.Also Date Published above header like Date Published:3rd February 2020.

Pleas Help.

Thanks
Raichand Ray

Comment: What have you tried to do?

Comment: For theme-specific questions it's best to check with the theme author for documentation or their own support section. This site focuses on custom code.